# MySQL Workbench on Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't starts after latest (Jun12) updates

Tags: 12.04, updates, mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench was working fine till today. I installed the regular updates and now its just doesnt starts. When started its just shows the 'opening screen' and nothing happens.

I tried re-installing it from synaptic but no luck. I use it all the time and now suffering a lot. Any help will be appreciated.

When run from terminal with: `mysql-workbench --log-level=debug3 --verbose`

It gives a long log. Please see at: http://pastebin.com/Z2t8pdZF

I see these error in the log but don't know what they mean and how it stopped working automatically,

```
/home/atul/.mysql/workbench/wb_state.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
/home/atul/.mysql/workbench/wb_state.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
/home/atul/.mysql/workbench/user_starters.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
/home/atul/.mysql/workbench/user_starters.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
/home/atul/.mysql/workbench/starters_settings.xml:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
/home/atul/.mysql/workbench/starters_settings.xml:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canonical and God knows what went wrong. But here is a fix:

Download:

For 64 bit systems:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/56565535/libzip1_0.9-3ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb

For 32 bit systems:
http://launchpadlibrarian.net/56565266/libzip1_0.9-3ubuntu0.1_i386.deb

Once downloaded, double click to install.

Now Download the latest version of My SQL workbench, Its for 11.10 but will work on 12.04. Make sure you download the version (32bit or 64 bit) suitable to you:
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/#downloads

Once downloaded, double click on it to install.

And you are done.

Atul Kakrana

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution that resolved my problem:

I (kind of) fixed mine by going to `/home/username/mysql/` and renaming (or deleting) the workbench folder.

It's ok and now my Worbench runs very well!

Answer (score 1):

I (kind of) fixed mine by going to `/home/<your username>/.mysql/` and renaming (or deleting) the `workbench` folder. All of your connections need to be re-entered, but it's worth it to get your database program back up and running. The only reason I'm saying this is, because this was the only way I could get mine to work, no other solutions on the internet worked for me. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, but this should work on any other version of Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of  renaming (or deleting) the `workbench` folder.You just have to delete `wb_options.xml` inside `/home/<your username>/.mysql/workbench/`.

This fixes the issue and moreover all your data residing in your database is still there.

This is definitely a better option than re-installing mysql-workbench again.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 13.04 I had the same problem to fix it

I ran

> sudo apt-get remove mysql-workbench
>
> sudo apt-get remove mysql-woorkbench-data

later removed workbench directory in

> /home/username/.mysql

and reinstalled mysql-workbench it started working

Comment: this also worked for 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted `~/.mysql/workbench/wb_options.xml` and now MySQLWorkBench starts ok.